# Dismiss view controller crashes the app with (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift

I have an issue with my app when i dismiss the controller, with lldb, I'm not doing anything wrong, ill provide the project and sample code here :

I present it here :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var cont = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Detail") as! Detail
    cont.link = indexPath.row
    self.view.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(cont, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

And dismiss it here:

```
@IBAction func disiss(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


}
```

My project is here :
https://yadi.sk/d/pSscby7ZicqSU

I think the issue happens when try to open and dismiss and open and dismiss quickly ! and sometimes i just open it and dismiss and it crashes ! and I'm testing on iPhone 6. I've just tried it on the simulator iPhone 6 and it crashes .

Comment: Your sample project is working fine.

Comment: sometimes it crashes and sometimes it works only ones, I'm very confused ! as a project it should work without bug !

Comment: Try to figure out the use case in which the app crashes. Someone will be able to help you then.

Comment: Can you try : `self.presentViewController(cont, animated: true, completion: nil)` . Check that app is crashing app in that too?

Comment: in this way i get the following error : @iAshish -> Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <PageMenuDemoStoryboard.CollectionViewController: 0x12fe038e0>. Thats why i used self.view.window.....

Comment: @AaoIi it is crashing from ViewController.swift `self.view.addSubview`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ViewController.swift

replace

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
 }
```

with

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

 }
```

Comment: My pleasure , I was expecting you will ask the reason but  :)

Comment: @Muhammad , actually Mr.@iAshish said that the reason was in adding subview in a comment ? or was it something else ? thats why i didn't ask ! :)